# Text file formatting using regular expression

Tags: unix

I am trying to format a below text file, record order will be always like this

```
Dept 0100 Batch Load Errors for 8/16/2016 4:45:56 AM 

Case 1111111111
Rectype: ABCD 
    Key:UMUM_REF_ID=A12345678,UMSV_SEQ_NO=1
        UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID 

Case 2222222222
Rectype: ABCD 
    Key:UMUM_REF_ID=B87654321,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2
        UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID 
        NTNB ERROR  :Invalid Value                       NTNB_MCTR_SUBJ=AMOD

Case 3333333333
Rectype: WXYZ 
    Key:UMUM_REF_ID=U19817250,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2
        UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
```

as output

```
1111111111~ABCD~UMUM_REF_ID=A12345678,UMSV_SEQ_NO=1~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
2222222222~ABCD~UMUM_REF_ID=B87654321,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID|NTNB ERROR  :Invalid Value NTNB_MCTR_SUBJ=AMOD
3333333333~WXYZ~UMUM_REF_ID=U19817250,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
```

I tried regular expression as below

```
sed -r '/^Case/!d;$!N;/\nRectype/!D;s/\s+$/ /;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1\n\1/;P;D' file.txt
```

but this is working only till Rectype row, not able to achieve rest.

Thank you.

Comment: The whitespace in the second line of the desired output appears to be longer than in the corresponding line of input. Is that intended?

Comment: @Beta: I just updated desired output, need to trim extra spaces if any

Comment: What are the rules governing how `Key:` is joined? First and second lines are fields separated by `~` and subsequent lines are joined with `|`?  Or are lines starting with `N` always joined with `|` and everything else with `~`? Or something else? And should all strings of >2 spaces be shrunk to 2, or could they be shrunk to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're not really looking for a regular expression. You're looking for text reformatting, and you appear to have selected regular expression matching in sed as the method by which you'll process fields.

Read about [XY problems here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Thankfully, you've included raw data and expected output, which is AWESOME for a new StackOverflow member. (Really! Yay you!) So I can recommend an alternative that will likely work better for you.

It is awk. Another command-line tool which, like sed, is installed on virtually every unix-like system on the planet.

```
$ awk -v RS= -v OFS="~" '!/^Case/{next} {sub(/^Key:/,"",$5); key=$5; for (f=6;f<=NF;f++) { if ($f=="NTNB") key=key "|"; else if ($f=="UMSV") key=key OFS; else key=key " "; key=key $f } print $2,$4,key}' inp2
1111111111~ABCD~UMUM_REF_ID=A12345678,UMSV_SEQ_NO=1~UMSV ERROR :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
2222222222~ABCD~UMUM_REF_ID=B87654321,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2~UMSV ERROR :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID|NTNB ERROR :Invalid Value NTNB_MCTR_SUBJ=AMOD
3333333333~WXYZ~UMUM_REF_ID=U19817250,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2~UMSV ERROR :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
```

Here's what's going on.

- `awk -v RS=` - This is important. It sets a "null" record separator, which tells awk that we're dealing with multi-line records. Records are terminated by a blank line, and fields within this record are separated by whitespace. (Space, tab, newline.)
- `-v OFS="~"` - Set an output field separator of tilde, for convenience.
- `$1!="Case"{next}` - If the current record doesn't have the word "Case" as its first field, it's not a line we can handle, so skip it.
- `sub(/^Key:/,"",$5); key=$5;` - Trim the word `Key` from the beginning of the fifth field, save the field to a variable.
- `for (f=6;f<=NF;f++) {` - Step through the remaining fields
- `if ($f=="NTNB") key=key "|";` - setting the appropriate field separator.
- `else if ($f=="UMSV") key=key OFS;` - ...
- `else key=key " ";` - Or space if the text doesn't look like a new field.
- `key=key $f }` - Finally, add the current field to our our running variable,
- `print $2,$4,key}` - and print everything.

NOTE: One thing this doesn't do is maintain spacing as you've shown in your "expected output" in your question. Two or more spaces will always be shrunk to just one space, since within each record, fields are separated by whitespace.

---

**UPDATE** per comments

Windows uses `\r\n` (CRLF) to end lines, whereas unix/linux use just `\n` (LF). Since your file is being generated in Windows, the "blank" lines actually contain an invisible CR, and `awk` never sees a record separator.

To see the "real" contents of your file, you can use tools like [`hexdump`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hexdump) or [`od`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=od). For example:

```
$ printf 'foo\r\nbar\r\n' | od -c
0000000    f   o   o  \r  \n   b   a   r  \r  \n
0000012
```

In your case, simply run:

```
$ od -c filename | less
```

(Or use `more` if less isn't available.)

Many systems have a package available called `dos2unix` which can convert text format.

If you don't have `dos2unix` available, you should be able to achieve the same thing using other tools. In GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' filename
```

Or in other sed variants, but with a shell (like bash) that supports format substitution (read `man sed` to see if you have a `-i` option):

```
sed $'s/\r$//' inputfile > outputfile
```

Or a little less precisely, as it will remove all CRs even if they're not at the end of the line, you could use `tr`:

```
tr -d '\015' < inputfile > outputfile
```

Or if perl is available, you can use a substitution expression that's almost identical to the one for sed (perl documentation is readily available to tell you what the options do):

```
perl -i -pe 's/\r\n$/\n/g' filename
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for solution you proposed, it worked perfectly for file format I have mentioned here(I created this sample file manually). But when I ran this code on another file with same format and same field tags, I am not getting desired result. The file I am trying to run code was created by Windows OS, so may be some garbage values are there instead of spaces and new lines. Unfortunately I can not upload the file here. Is there any way I can identify what exactly it contain so I can format it to make this code work.

Comment: Glad this helped. Yes, you've hit the nail on the head -- I've added an update rather than putting the explanation and solution in comments.

Comment: Wow !! After running command you provided, I could see lots of \r\n in file. I removed \r and ran your solution. Everything ran successfully.

Comment: One more help needed. I ran the code with file(more than 10000 records) and during unit testing I realize, file also have records those are not terminated by blank line (there is no blank line between two "Case" records). Because of this two records being concatenated in one.                                                  I tried changing "RC=\n" in code instead of "NULL" but not working.

Comment: No, setting `RC` to an empty value is the magic that causes Awk to run in multi-line-record mode. As the `gawk` man page says: *"If RS is set to the null string, then records are separated by blank lines.  When RS is set to the null string, the newline character always acts as a field separator".

Comment: If you want to make sure you have blank lines as record separators, you could pre-process your file with `awk '/^Case /{print ""}1'`.  This will insert a blank line before *every* line that starts with `Case`. Empty records (i.e. double blank lines) should be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are awesome !!!! Your detail description of each command really empowered me with awk knowledge.